# reverse SetLayeredWindowAttributes

Tags: java, winapi, alpha-transparency

I am using this code for sharing the screen. I have an air desktop application(transparent backgound) which I have created. I don't want that window to be shared i.e it should not be visible to client. So I am using SetLayeredWindowAttributes to hide the window then capture the desktop and send the image to clients and then unhide my window.

I am using SetLayeredWindowAttributes to make my window transparent. How to reverse that i.e make my window visible again.

Here is my code

```
private int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
private int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;
private int LWA_ALPHA = 0x00000002;
private int LWA_COLORKEY = 0x00000001;
int winLong = User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
User32Extra.INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, winLong | WS_EX_LAYERED);
User32Extra.INSTANCE.SetWindowPos(hwnd, null, 100, 100, 100, 100,(0x0002) | (0x0001) | (0x0004) | (0x0020));
User32Extra.INSTANCE.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, null, 128,LWA_ALPHA);
/* My code*/
User32Extra.INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(hwnd, winLong & ~WS_EX_LAYERED);
User32Extra.INSTANCE.SetWindowPos(hwnd, null, 100, 100, 100, 100,(0x0002) | (0x0001) | (0x0004) | (0x0020));
User32Extra.INSTANCE.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, null, 128,LWA_ALPHA);
```

What parameters are to be sent to make my window visible again?

Comment: Recall `SetWindowLong` removing the flag  `winLong & ~WS_EX_LAYERED` (`SetWindowLongPtr` is preferred)

Comment: Or set the alpha to 255.

Comment: My window is a transparent window. After updating the above modifications, My window is visible but the transparency of the window is lost.

Comment: @Vishnu: As it should because those modifications are intended to remove the transparency from the window.  What is the real problem you are having? What are you trying to accomplish? The code you have shown is not hiding the window, only making it partially transparent (btw, why are you setting the `crKey` parameter when you are not using the `LWA_COLORKEY` flag?).  So what are you trying to "make visible"? The suggested modifications will make the window opaque again, but it sounds like that is not what you really want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have updated the question. My window's background is transparent. After hiding and unhiding it, background transparency is lost.

Comment: @Vishnu: Again, the suggested modifications ARE SUPPOSED to remove the transparency. That is what happens when you remove the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style (and you cannot use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` without `WS_EX_LAYERED`), or set the window's alpha to 255 (opaque).  If you are just trying to hide the window from being captured, why are you using alpha transparency to accomplish that?  A window with an alpha above 0 is visible. Just use `ShowWindow()` with the `SW_HIDE`/`SW_SHOW` flags instead. If your window is already transparent before hiding, this will preserve the original transparency.

Comment: @Vishnu, otherwise, you have to remember the original transparency values before hiding, then restore them after showing, without removing `WS_EX_LAYERED`.  You can use `GetLayeredWindowAttributes()` to retrieve the original values and then `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` to restore them.